# how to use instence variable in static area if class is autowired in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

```
/* This condition will ariese when we will read the values from property file and there a change to use this value in static area  */

  @Component

    public class Employee{

    String name="radhe";

    }

    public class Address{

    @Autowired

    Employee employee;

    public static void display(){

    employee.name;

    }

    }
```

Comment: Hi @vishnu, I'm afraid it is not at all clear what problem you want to solve. You can't instance variables from a static context. But that is just a Java property and is independent of Spring. Please add a description what you want to achieve and we might be able to help.

Comment: Hi JensSchauder, I have a class Employee in that there is some variable, i want to read the values from property file using @ConfigurationProperties and i have to use threse variable in static area. If i'll take static variable in Employee class then i can't read the values from property file

Comment: Why does this section have to be static? Why don't you use for example an `Employee` Spring Bean and inject it where ever you currently use the static variable.

Also: What is the semantical meaning of displaying "the employees" name without having any meaning full definition of "the employee" since you can have many of those?

Comment: No sir, Employee is just a class name for a example, class name can be anything as well as variables may have some other name but concept was, how to use an instance variable in static area

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

1.Constructor injection

```
public class Address{

      private static Employee employee;

      @Autowired
      public Address(Employee employee){
        Address.employee= employee;
      }

      public static void display(){
        employee.name;
      }
 }
```

2.Post construct

```
 public class Address{

         private static Employee employee;

         @Autowired
         private Employee employeeI;

         @PostConstruct
         public void init() {
           Address.employee= employeeI;
         }

          public static void display(){
            employee.name;
          }
     }
```

Comment: Please read my question again , After applying your logic i'm getting null value I have a class Employee in that there is some variable, i want to read the values from property file using @ConfigurationProperties and i have to use threse variable in static area. If i'll take static variable in Employee class then i can't read the values from property file

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to use instance variable in static block, you may have to change your logic to incorporate the same.